# Marionette: Reassign class to every third itemView after removing from collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I have a collection and a corresponding view of items. When initially rendering, the composite view sends an `indexClass` to the `itemView` every third item so it can display correctly.

Now, say, I want to remove that item from the collection, and have the view update. I now need to re-render the whole collection assigning new `indexClass`es. Right now, it removes the item from the composite view, but all other item views still have the same class(es) as they did before--messing up the styling.

How would I do this? Are there any performance issues here?

I've also thought of just using CSS3 selector `:nth-child(3n)` just to save me the trouble. The styling isn't crucial, so it would be fine even if the browser didn't support CSS3.

```
    var ListItemView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
        template: '#list-item',
        tagName: 'li',

        events: {
            'click .delete': 'delete'
        },

        onRender : function () {
            if (this.options.indexClass) {
                this.$el.addClass(this.options.indexClass);
            }
        },

        delete: function() {
            this.model.collection.remove(this.model);
        }
    });

    var ListComposite = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({

        itemView: ListItemView,
        itemViewContainer: "ul",
        itemViewOptions : function (model, index) {
            if ((index + 1) % 3 == 0) {
              return { indexClass: "rowend" };
            } else {
              return {};
            }
        },

        template: "#list"
    });
```

Comment: You would need to render the whole view again. As your logic is tied up with the class logic

Comment: I use CSS3 for things like that and it works great, if you are worried about compatibility you can use jQuery to do it for you.

http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS 3 selector is the best way to go (its more of an appearance issue anyway)

[Can I Use - CSS3 Selector](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3)

Looks like 87.18% of global usage is good for  it

I would also look at [Selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/) for IE 6-8 functionality

If you are supporting IE < 6 well then backbone breaks.

Other options :

- Is your data really a list of groups ?
- Can the style be applied to the container element ? i.e. UL border-right
- Would you be better off not having a set number in a group but be responsive?

Understandably these are off the wall suggestions for your data but depending on what it is, and what you are trying to do one may actually work.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions, Hurricanepkt. I ended up going with the CSS3 Selector.